# AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'- Python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

This is my first project with Python, which I wrote online by Repl.it, (disclaimer: I have very little programming experience), it's supposed to turn on an LED when I receive a message, but this error appears when I run it (I am running it on Windows 10, 64 bits).

```
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import time
import serial
import os

os.system('cls')
**ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)**
ser.close()
ser.open()
```

It says that in the bolded line, 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial', what can I do in order to fix it?
Thanks in advance and sorry for any dumb mistake I may have committed.

Comment: Have you installed `pyserial`? Do you perhaps have another module named `serial` on your Python path that is shadowing it?

Answer (score 0):

Repl.it for whatever reason interprets `import serial` as the package 'serial', not 'pyserial', even if you manually specify pyserial as a requirement. This is just an idiosyncrasy with the repl.it virtual machine as far as I can tell. Run it on your local machine with pyserial installed and it should work fine.

Comment: Not to mention, 'COM20' is not going to exist or be accessible on a repl.it VM.